# What permissions are needed to delete an object from a specific bucket in S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I am trying to create an IAM policy for a lambda role which will give permissions to delete an object. If I do not specify the resource this policy works, but I would like to limit it to the specific bucket:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname"
            ]
        }
    ] }
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Why do you have PutObject, GetObject, and ListBucket in your policy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-policies-s3.html)

```
        {
    "Version":"2012-10-17",
    "Statement":[
        {
            "Effect":"Allow",
            "Action":["s3:ListBucket","s3:GetBucketLocation"],
            "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::awsexamplebucket1"
        },
        {
            "Effect":"Allow",
            "Action":[
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::awsexamplebucket1/*"
        }
    ]
    }
```

Make sure, the IAM role for your lambda has [trust policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-intro-execution-role.html) setup.

Comment: Amazing. I guess the acl and get bucket location was what I couldnt figure out.

Answer (score -1):

> In my case I am not able to delete object . 
>  But can upload object .So I update my bucket policy after that working fine.

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "*"
        },
        "Action": [
            "s3:ListBucket",
            "s3:GetBucketLocation"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::YourBucketName"
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "*"
        },
        "Action": [
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:PutObjectAcl",
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:GetObjectAcl",
            "s3:DeleteObject"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::YourBucketName/*"
    }
]
```

}

Comment: Because of we can not  set principal is empty in policy

Comment: This would allow anyone to read and write from/to the bucket. When defining principals you should be following least privilege access, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/security-best-practices.html