# I can't delete a file from AWS S3 Bucket with Javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-policies

Whenever I try to delete an object with the Javascript SDK, I get an error saying access denied. However, I can upload files correctly. Can someone help me with this?

My policies for the bucket:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::twitter-clone-image-storage-zrs/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

My function for deleting files:

```
const s3 = new S3({
  region,
  accessKeyId,
  secretAccessKey,
});

export const deleteFile = (picture_key) => {
  const params = {
    Bucket: bucketName,
    Key: picture_key,
  };

  return s3.deleteObject(params).promise();
};
```

Comment: Check this similar question for the iam policies for the bucket, if that's work: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65566850/12326605

Comment: Make sure picture_key does not begin with a forward slash. Modify your deleteFile function to be async, and then await the call to it.